# how to import java servlet project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm not able to run the java online banking project in eclipse which I downloaded although I import it in eclipse and also have tomcat 7.0 configured with eclipse but the project is not running also there are so many .java files i do not know which i would run first?Also when i try to run the whole project by right clicking on the project directory and select run as option but run on server option is not there but the project which I did on eclipse from start is running without error? please help me any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way - you can create an empty servlet project and just add the class files.

Otherwise - you can just read and analyze project file - perhaps you can understand that this Maven project. Maybe the project is built as a tomcat-plugin project.

Comment: wait a minute! let me try the easiest way

Comment: Find the link to Google "how to create a servlet project in Eclipse." After that (if the structure of the new project coincides with the structure of the imported project) - a portable classrooms. When you try to build the project in any case you will see information about missing libraries and classes.

P.S. Another thing, if you see that the file structure is not the same

Comment: Do I understand correctly that import the project "as an existing Eclipse project" does not work?

Comment: I tried the easiest way and it works fine now thnks

Comment: its not a existing project in my eclipse i have downloaded it from a blog which said they developed it by using eclipse.

Comment: everything works fine now except i don't know how to connect it with jdbc can u help me out ? I  Do not know how i should configure jdbc in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Your project may require the web module facet.
[Eclipse facets](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html) are meta data about a project that tell eclipse how to treat it. Normally eclipse would do this itself based on the existence of a web.xml, but who knows what might have happened.

Try right-clicking on your project > properties > project facets > enable 'Dynamic Web Module'

Then you can right click on the tomcat server you're managing with eclipse > add or remove projects > add your project

Then you should be able to start up tomcat.